# MPDF Not displaying correct CSS

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, mpdf

```html
//this is the code at the page that generates pdf

$string = get_include_contents('pdf/draydocument/index.php');

//print_r($string);
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($string);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->Output();
```

```css
.heading {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.body {
  margin-top: 29px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.text-block {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.text-block-2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.text-field {
  margin-right: -453px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.bold-text {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 9px;
  color: #ffa705;
}

.paragraph {
  width: 60%;
  margin-right: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.div-block {
  margin: -144px 0px 1px 1200px;
}

.text-block-3 {
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-left: -600px;
}

.heading-2 {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.heading-3 {
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 117px;
  margin-right: 400px;
  margin-left: -32px;
  color: #ffa705;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.grid {
  grid-template-areas: "Area";
}

.columns {
  width: 35%;
  border: 1px none #000;
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-2 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-3 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-4 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-5 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-6 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-7 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-8 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-9 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-10 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-11 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-12 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-13 {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.columns-2 {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.column-14 {
  padding-right: 35px;
}

.column-15 {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.columns-3 {
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.column-16 {
  height: 30px;
}

.column-17 {
  height: 30px;
}

.column-18 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-19 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-20 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-21 {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-22 {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-23 {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.image {
  width: 600px;
}

.div-block-2 {
  width: 60px;
}

.text-block-4 {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: -600px;
}

.columns-4 {
  width: 35%;
}

.columns-5 {
  width: 35%;
}

.columns-6 {
  width: 35%;
}

.columns-7 {
  width: 35%;
}

.columns-8 {
  width: 35%;
}

.text-block-5 {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.bold-text-2 {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.bold-text-3 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--  This site was created in Webflow. http://www.webflow.com  -->
<!--  Last Published: Fri Nov 08 2019 22:38:51 GMT+0000 (UTC)  -->
<html data-wf-page="5dc492ebb03ec1759b3c5d8c" data-wf-site="5dc492ebb03ec16cc23c5d8b">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Delivery Order</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta content="Webflow" name="generator">
<link href="http://freightcube.net/pdf/draydocument/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://freightcube.net/pdf/draydocument/css/webflow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/puneets-blank-site-1bae2e.webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">WebFont.load({  google: {    families: ["Montserrat:100,100italic,200,200italic,300,300italic,400,400italic,500,500italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,900,900italic","Varela Round:400"]  }});</script>
  <!-- [if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif] -->
  <script type="text/javascript">!function(o,c){var n=c.documentElement,t=" w-mod-";n.className+=t+"js",("ontouchstart"in o||o.DocumentTouch&&c instanceof DocumentTouch)&&(n.className+=t+"touch")}(window,document);</script>
  <link href="" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="" rel="apple-touch-icon">
</head>
<body class="body">
  <div class="div-block-2"></div>
  <p class="paragraph">123 E 9TH ST, SUITE 332<br>UPLAND, CA 91786<br>PHONE: 909-285-2370<br>EMAIL: ops@freightcube.net</p>
  <h1 class="heading-3">           DRAYAGE DELIVERY ORDER</h1>
  <div class="columns w-row">
    <div class="column w-col w-col-4">
      <h6>OCEAN CARRIER/SSL :<br>php code</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="column-2 w-col w-col-4">
      <h6>LOCATION/TERMINAL :<br>php code</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="column-3 w-col w-col-4">
      <h6>PORT :<br>php code</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns-4 w-row">
    <div class="column-4 w-col w-col-4">
      <h6>MASTER BOL :<br>PHP</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="column-5 w-col w-col-4">
      <h6>ARRIVAL DATE/CUT OFF DATE :<br>PHP</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="column-6 w-col w-col-4">
      <h6>TRUCKING COMPANY:<br>PHP</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns-5 w-row">
    <div class="column-7 w-col w-col-3">
      <h6>CONTAINER :<br>PHP</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="column-8 w-col w-col-3">
      <h6>HOUSE BOL :<br>PHP</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="column-9 w-col w-col-3">
      <h6>ENTRY NO :<br>PHP</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="column-10 w-col w-col-3">
      <h6>CUSTOMER REFERENCE :<br>PHP</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns-6 w-row">
    <div class="column-11 w-col w-col-6">
      <h6>DELIVERY/PICKUP ADDRESS:<br>PHP</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="column-12 w-col w-col-6">
      <h6>SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS:<br>PHP</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns-7 w-row">
    <div class="column-18 w-col w-col-3">
      <h6>NO. OF PKGS</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="column-19 w-col w-col-6">
      <h6>DESCRIPTION OF GOODS</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="column-20 w-col w-col-3">
      <h6>WEIGHT</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns-8 w-row">
    <div class="column-21 w-col w-col-3">
      <div class="text-block-5"><strong>PHP CODE FOR NO. OF PACKAGES</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-22 w-col w-col-6">
      <div><strong class="bold-text-2">PHP FOR DISCRIPTION</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-23 w-col w-col-3">
      <div><strong class="bold-text-3">PHP FOR WEIGHT</strong></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h4>RECEIVED IN GOOD ORDER BY :<br>‍</h4>
  <script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.220afd743d.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/webflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- [if lte IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif] -->
</body>
</html>
```

[link to code](https://github.com/puneet812/transverse/tree/master)I am using mpdf for my php application to generate pdf pages. I recently generated an html page using a drag and drop html builder which also provides source code with css. so i copied the exact css on the page using . When mpdf generates the pdf it is not showing css correctly. it looks like width issues but i tried to reduce width of all divs and still encounter the same problem just with smaller appearing columns. please help. here is how it shows[image: how it shows] and how it should show[image: how it should be]

Comment: sorry, link to code included in the very beginning of question. Thanks

Comment: Code needs to be *in* the question and not as an external resource. I don't make the rules, Stack Overflow does.

Comment: Hello, inserted in question

Comment: Those top two link tags aren't part of the document. I would assume that's your problem.

Comment: i just insterted those for you to see css and for snippet to work.Those are the external links to css files as they are too big to fit in question's code section

Answer (score 1):

mPDF has limited abilities in handling floated blocks. Use a HTML table to make sure it is displayed  correctly (your data is somewhat tabular, so it is the right thing to do anyway).